# How to randomize Java "if" statement order or the order code is executed?

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am writing the depth first search algorithm for a Ghost entity in a Pacman game. The Ghost has to search for a path to the Pacman. But even though there is  a path to the Pacman, the depth first search algorithm
will not always find it because of the way the if statements are order.

```
     private boolean searchPath(
                int[][] maze, int x, int y, List<Point> path )
{
    System.out.println( "Inky.searchPath: " + "(" + x + "," + y +  ")" );
    if ( !grid.isValid( new Location( x, y ) ) )
    {
        System.out.println( "Inky.searchPath: Location is not valid" );
        return false;
    }

    //Target
    if ( maze[x][y] == 9 )
    {
        path.add( new Point( x, y ) );
        return true;
    }

    //Changing point to point visited
    if ( maze[x][y] == 0 )
    {
        maze[x][y] = 2;

        //Need something that executes these if statements at     random

        //Searching one block down
        if ( searchPath( maze, x - 1, y, path ) )
        {
            path.add( new Point( x, y ) );
            return true;
        }

        //Searching one block up
        if ( searchPath( maze, x + 1, y, path ) )
        {
            path.add( new Point( x, y ) );
            return true;
        }

        //Searching one block left
        if ( searchPath( maze, x, y - 1, path ) )
        {
            path.add( new Point( x, y ) );
            return true;
        }

        //Searching one block right
        if ( searchPath( maze, x, y + 1, path ) )
        {
            path.add( new Point( x, y ) );
            return true;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Inky.searchPath: Path not found");
    return false;

}
```

As you can see the order of the if statements is
1. Search one block down
2. Search one block up
3. Search one block left
4. Search one block right

So if the Ghost enters a situation where there is a open block to the left, it will go until there is not open block to the left, then the second step will come into action and the Ghost will go back again to where it started, because the second step searches X-1.

So, my question is, is there a way to random the order in which the if statements are executed?

Comment: put the if statements in seperate methods, call them in order based on your data. but why would you want to do so?

Comment: If your search is actually exhaustive, then why would the _order_ of steps taken affect the final outcome?

Comment: @ Stultuske As you can see it is a recursive method so I don't think that will work.

Comment: Tip: to address a comment to someone add his user name like so: @Stultuske

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because sometimes the Ghost gets stuck and I get a "path not found" error, even though there is path, I assumed this was because the search algorithm is getting stuck in a loop, because of the order of the if statements.

Comment: @ShamsAnsari even recursive methods can call other methods.

Comment: Then the algorithm has a problem, and simply randomizing the steps taken may not completely fix this anyway.  BTW, Pac Man would love this maze if the ghosts keep getting stuck :-)

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  You do not want to _"randomize Java “if” statement order"_ but instead need to fix your algorithm so that it generates motion towards the updated position of the PacMan at each iteration, taking into account the directions available from the current ghost's position.  This will be more complex than what you currently have. I.e. at each iteration you need to calculate the shortest path from the ghost to PacMan and begin moving along that path.  You do this on each time quantum.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, thanks, I'll try to look for a better algorithm.

Comment: Please take the time to respond to the two answers proposed.

Answer (score 0):

To randomise directions you could :

```
    //introduce a collection of directions
    private List<int[]> directions = Arrays.asList (new int[][] {{1,0},{-1,0}, {0,1}, {0,-1}}); //right, left, down, up

    //use it
    Collections.shuffle(directions);
    for(int[] dir : directions){

        boolean result = searchPath( maze, x + dir[0], y + dir[1], path ) ;
        //todo handle result 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Put your if statements in switch generate a random number and use switch to
>   decide which if to execute.

```
        //Need something that executes these if statements at     random

       int random=ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,5);

       switch(random)

       {

        case 1:
        //Searching one block down
        if ( searchPath( maze, x - 1, y, path ) )
        {
            path.add( new Point( x, y ) );
            return true;
        }
        break;

         case 2:    
        //Searching one block up
        if ( searchPath( maze, x + 1, y, path ) )
        {
            path.add( new Point( x, y ) );
            return true;
        }
        break;

        case 3:
        //Searching one block left
        if ( searchPath( maze, x, y - 1, path ) )
        {
            path.add( new Point( x, y ) );
            return true;
        }
        break;

        case 4:
        //Searching one block right
        if ( searchPath( maze, x, y + 1, path ) )
        {
            path.add( new Point( x, y ) );
            return true;
        }
        break;

        }
```